# how to write mock test in laravel (IOC)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-testing

i dont know how to write mock test for my service

here is my **compressContract** Interface

```php
interface compressContract
{
    public function compress();
}
```

here is my **ZipCompress** class

```php
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers\My\compression;


class ZipCompress implements compressContract
{

    public function compress()
    {
        var_dump('im zip compression');
    }
}
```

and here is my **compressManager** class

```php
class compressManager
{
    public compressContract $compressContract;

    public function __construct(compressContract $compressContract)
    {
        $this->compressContract = $compressContract;
    }

    public function compressFile(Request $request)
    {
        //do somthing
    }
}
```

and here is **AppServiceProvider** class in the boot method

```php
public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CompressContract::class , ZipCompress::class);
    }
```

i read articles about mocking a class but i cant write mock for these class

Comment: Did my answer help your problem or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly basics, class names are pascal cased. `compressContract` should be `CompressContract`.

A unit test, mocking the compression contract would look like this. Laravel has helpers in the test cases to help you actual bind the mocked instance to the container. This is described in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking).

```
/** @test **/
public function your_test()
{
    $this->mock(CompressContract::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
         $mock->shouldReceive('compress')->once()->andReturn('If you want correct return');
    });

    // call your class or http test your controller.
}
```